# Open jsp pages inside tabs

Tags: javascript, jsp, tabs

I am trying to open jsp page in view of the tab(tab contents are jsp pages) that has been clicked but instead it navigates to that page in new window and tabs disappear.

here is my `js` for `tabs`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".tabbable").find(".tab").hide();
        $(".tabbable").find(".tab").first().show();
        $(".tabbable").find(".tabs li").first().find("a").addClass("active");
        $(".tabbable").find(".tabs").find("a").click(function(){
            tab = $(this).attr("href");
            $(".tabbable").find(".tab").hide();
            $(".tabbable").find(".tabs").find("a").removeClass("active");
            $(tab).show();
            $(this).addClass("active");
            return false;
        });
});
```

and `jsp`

```
<body>
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="pages/first.jsp">first</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/second.jsp">second</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/third.jsp">third</a></li>
    </ul>
 <div id="first" class="tab">
  contents of this tab.
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I am new to `JavaScript`, Where am I wrong ?

Note: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sajjadpz/a6hq3fvx/1/) as per few suggestions.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904944/how-to-open-a-link-from-within-jquery-ui-tabs-inside-said-tab?lq=1)
solved my problem with minor tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

According to your post, I assume you are using jQuery. My answer is based on that assumption so if I am wrong, please ignore this post.

I am also assuming that you intent to show the content of each tab inside the div with id 'first'.

First of all, I don't see why the code you posted would open the tab content in a new window, as returning false in an event handler prevents default behaviour from happening (in anchor elements this default behaviour is opening the referenced page), maybe I am missing somenthing here.

As per your post, you are not getting the content of any of those pages anywhere. I have added some extra lines in your code in order to do so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $(".tabbable").find(".tab").hide();
            $(".tabbable").find(".tab").first().show();
            $(".tabbable").find(".tabs li").first().find("a").addClass("active");
            $(".tabbable").find(".tabs").find("a").click(function(){
                    tab = $(this).attr("href");
                    $(".tabbable").find(".tab").hide();
                    $(".tabbable").find(".tabs").find("a").removeClass("active");
                    //$(tab).show(); -> This line does nothing, as no element matches the given selector
                    // Get html content making a GET request
                    // see: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
                    $.get( tab, function( data ) {
                        // Add the html content to the container
                        $( "#first" ).html( data );
                    });
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    return false;
                });
        });
```

Basically what that couple of lines are doing is: 1) make a request to the server to get the required content; 2) Paste that content within the div with id 'first'.

Once again, if that's not what you intend to do you can just discard this answer. If there's anything wrong with my code, or you have any doubt regarding my solution feel free to post a question.

Comment: I have tried as you suggested, still the same result, I am updating my answer with JsFiddle, please have a look.

Comment: As I said in my previous answer, I was assumming that you were using jQuery library (because of the use you were giving to the $ variable), you haven't include that library in the jsfiddle though. I have updated your jsfiddle to make use of jQuery library. Because of security restrictions those pages' content won't load. Could you try again with your code, but this time including jQuery library (you can get it from a CDN, e.g. from google's CDN - https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)

Comment: I see no change in jsfiddle, even if I include jQuery library, the contents of the jsp page open up in new window and tabs disappear since control is shifted to that jsp page. where as I want that page to appear in the same tab and tabs should not disappear.